# VirtualBox bug[?] when Chainloading Grub2

Tags: ubuntu, fedora, virtualbox, grub2

Regarding this: [How to install Fedora&Ubuntu with encrypted VG's on one disk?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11289/how-to-install-fedoraubuntu-with-encrypted-vgs-on-one-disk/11509#11509)

So booted into Ubuntu..and I run this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# show the bootlist of grub when booting pc
sed -i.backup 's/^GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=/#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=/' /etc/default/grub
sed -i 's/^GRUB_TIMEOUT=10/GRUB_TIMEOUT=5/' /etc/default/grub
# update-grub # we will use this later too.. don't need it here

# add the "chainload grub" function
cp /etc/grub.d/40_custom /etc/grub.d/40_custom.backup
echo "#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 \$0
menuentry 'FEDORA' {
    insmod chain
    set root=(hd0,3)
    chainloader +1
}" > /etc/grub.d/40_custom
chmod 755 /etc/grub.d/40_custom
update-grub

sync
sync
sync
```

ok, great no error messages..

I'm using: VirtualBox-3.2-3.2.12_68302_fedora14-1.i686

Now I want to reboot the virtualbox machine to test the whole thing..this is what I get a few seconds after i select "FEDORA" in the grub2 bootlist:

[pichost #1](http://img130.imageshack.us/img130/2227/wtfaf.png) - [pichost #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1SfJ.png)

great! .. :(
other things: [VBox.log](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=0DfVVFTC); [2011-04-17-15-23-37.048-VirtualBox-12365.log](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=mppQBzk1)

Can anyone help me? Is there a workaround for this bug?

Thank you!

Comment: Given that it's a bug, I really recommend reporting it to the authors.

Comment: I updated to VirtualBox 4.0.4..it's the same

Comment: http://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/8742